# Using a table to lookup multiple IDs on one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables I am using at work to help me gain experience in writing SQL queries.  One table contains a list of `Applications` and has three columns -
 `Application_Name`, `Application_Contact_ID` and `Business_Contact_ID`. I then have a separate table called `Contacts` with two columns - `Contact_ID` and `Contact_Name`.  I am trying to write a query that will list the `Application_Name` and `Contact_Name` for both the `Applications_Contact_ID` and `Business_Contact_ID` columns instead of the ID number itself.

I understand I need to JOIN the two tables but I haven't quite figured out how to formulate the correct statement. Help Please!

APPLICATIONS TABLE:

```
+------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| Application_Name | Application_Contact_ID | Business_Contact_ID |
+------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| Adobe            |                     23 |                  23 |
| Word             |                     52 |                  14 |
| NotePad++        |                     44 |                 989 |
+------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

CONTACTS TABLE:

```
+------------+--------------+
| Contact_ID | Contact_Name |
+------------+--------------+
|         23 | Tim          |
|         52 | John         |
|         14 | Jen          |
|         44 | Carl         |
|        989 | Sam          |
+------------+--------------+
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| Application_Name | Application_Contact_Name | Business_Contact_Name |
+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| Adobe            | Tim                      | Tim                   |
| Word             | John                     | Jen                   |
| NotePad++        | Carl                     | Sam                   |
+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

I've tried the below but it is only returning the name for one of the columns:

`SELECT Application_Name, Application_Contact_ID, Business_Contact_ID, Contact_Name
FROM Applications
JOIN Contact ON Contact_ID = Application_Contact_ID`

Comment: What database is this? Oracle, Sql Server?

Comment: Also, post what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty critical and 101 part of SQL. Consider reading [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974786/joining-one-table-multiple-times-to-other-tables) on a different question, which explains the joins in more depth. The trick to your query, is that you have to join the `CONTACTS` table twice, which is a bit hard to visualize, because you have to go there for both the `application_contact_id` and `business_contact_id`.

There are many flavors of joins (`INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, etc.), which you'll want to familiarize yourself with for the future reference. Consider reading this article at the very least: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php.

```
SELECT t1.application_name Application_Name,
  t2.contact_name Application_Contact_name,
  t3.contact_name Business_Contact_name
FROM applications t1
INNER JOIN contacts ON t2 t1.Application_Contact_ID = t2.contact_id -- join contacts for appName
INNER JOIN contacts ON t3 t1.business_Contact_ID = t3.contact_id; -- join contacts for busName
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding some context. An answer should at least *try* to explain the solution.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you for taking the time to explain!