# Using data from 2 SQL tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a script that accesses a database and loops through the various items within the shop. I am attempting to access another table that contains users in the application and their points balance. When I am using my script, I am getting results duplicated three times per item. So I have 6 items within my shopitems table, but I am getting back 18 results, i.e., item 1 3 times, item 2 3 times, etc. I am wondering how I can fix this. The only column I want from the listings table is their points.

```
<?php 




include('../config.php');
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM shopitems CROSS JOIN listings");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$balance = $row['points'];
$cost = $row['itemcost'];

if ($balance < $cost) {
  $status = 'Not enough points';  
  } 
  else{
  $status = 'Purchase';
  }
echo'

      
  
        <div class="col-lg mb-md-0 mb-4">
          <div class="card border rounded shadow-none">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="my-3 pt-2 text-center">
                <img src="'.$row['itemimage'].'" alt="Basic Image" height="140">
              </div>
              <h3 class="card-title text-center text-capitalize mb-1">'.$row['itemname'].'</h3>

              <div class="text-center">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <sup class="h6 pricing-currency mt-3 mb-0 me-1 text-primary">P</sup>
                  <h1 class="display-4 mb-0 text-primary">'.$row['itemcost'].'</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
<br/>

<a href="./protected/webhook-alerts/shop-purchase.php?desc='.$row['itemdesc'].'" method="post" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-grid w-100 post">'.$status.'</a>
            </div>
          </div>
    

     


  ';

}
}catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Why use cross join instead of inner join?

Comment: I tried inner join already previous to posting and it's still looping my results with duplicates

Comment: Can you share as to what you tried using `Inner Join`. Post the edit in the question just by make a section at bottom `Edit: What i have i tried` like

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM shopitems INNER JOIN listings");` @Adi - I need all data from shopitems table, listings table I only need the points balance, I can currently get the points balance but it is duplicating the results

Comment: You should have an `ON` clause that relates the two tables.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` clause returns a full cross product of the two tables. So every `shopitem` will be repeated for every `listing`

Comment: I had a hunch, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974786/joining-one-table-multiple-times-to-other-tables

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON listings' at line 1

Comment: I got some kind of join to work, but I don't understand how it works as there is no correlating data to do the ON listings.xyz = shopitems.xyz or what I am meant to be referencing

Comment: The only column I want from listings is `points` then I need all the data from `shopitems`

Comment: What "points balance" are you referring to? Presumably you have three records in `listings`, what do they each refer to, and what exact data are you trying to fetch from them?

Comment: Within `listings` there are more columns than `shopitems`, the only column within table `listings` I'd like to grab data from is called `points`. There are no similar columns or rows all the data in both tables is different. Within `shopitems` table I'd like to pull ALL data. `listings` or `shopitems` could have more rows added in the future which is why It's important I don't get the duplicates based on row count in `listings`

Comment: do you mean to say that there is no relation between `shopitems` and `listings`? For example an `id` being referenced from `shopitems->listings` or vice versa?

Comment: It would help everyone _a lot_ if you posted a sample of the database data you're working with, and a sample of the query result you're trying to get from that sample. You can [edit] your question to include it

Comment: There is ID for users and ID for shop items but they don't relate; the data in both tables is different, All I want to do, as stated, is pull all the data from shop items and then pull all the data from listings and get points column or just points column alone

Comment: I am trying to get: all the '.$row['xyz'].' from shopitems and '.$row['points'].' from the listings table

Comment: Maybe you just need two separate queries. If there is no relationship between the two pieces of data then it makes no logical sense to select them together

Comment: I tried to separate queries; do you think you'd be able to provide a sample that would do what I need using the code I already put in the original post? Appreciated.

Comment: If you provide some proper sample data and example of the expected final result (based on that sample) as I requested previously then maybe yes I can. Without that there's always going to be a slight element of guesswork or assumptions, which can only waste time. Thanks

Comment: Column points is within the listings table; it contains a points count and is assigned to $balance which checks the balance against the items cost. itemcost,, itemimage, itemname, and itemdesc are all within the shopitems table. there is 6 rows currently. I want to pull all rows from the shopitems table and loop through them, as you can see in my code. I currently have duplicates using my current method, as listings have 3 rows, so I am getting 18 results instead of the expected 6. My expected result would be the six shop items (or more if added to the table in the future with no duplicates)

Comment: Whilst still retaining my access to the "points" column in the other table - listings.

Comment: It would be so much clearer if you [edit] the question and provide some _actual data_ and an _actual example_ of what you want to see on the screen at the end, rather than just a description. That's what I asked you to provide. There are still uncertainties. For example if listings has 3 rows then which one should the points value be taken from? Or is it a sum of all of the values? Or something else?

Comment: Points are selected using WHERE username = '$user->username'

Comment: So we need to use that to grab the users points

Comment: As currently, it is returning all 3 rows with all 3 points counts, I am guessing, which is why my results are duplicated

Comment: Your question lacks the most important detail: WHY you are trying join these unrelated table

Comment: `Points are selected using WHERE username = '$user->username'`...well that's the first time you've mentioned that, and it certainly isn't shown in your question already. Remember we are not mind-readers! Anyway, there's just about enough to have a go at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two tables appear to be basically unrelated, so a JOIN of any sort doesn't appear to make sense. It sounds like you simply you need two queries. Then you can use PHP to put the different pieces of data in the right place in the output.

Something like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmtListings = $conn->prepare("SELECT points FROM listings WHERE username = :username");
$stmtListings->execute(["username" => $user->username]);
$balanceRow = $stmtListings->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$balance = $balanceRow['points'];

$stmtItems = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM shopitems");
$stmtItems->execute();

while($row = $stmtItems->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  $cost = $row['itemcost'];

  if ($balance < $cost) {
    $status = 'Not enough points';  
  } 
  else{
    $status = 'Purchase';
  }
echo'
        <div class="col-lg mb-md-0 mb-4">
          <div class="card border rounded shadow-none">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="my-3 pt-2 text-center">
                <img src="'.$row['itemimage'].'" alt="Basic Image" height="140">
              </div>
              <h3 class="card-title text-center text-capitalize mb-1">'.$row['itemname'].'</h3>

              <div class="text-center">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <sup class="h6 pricing-currency mt-3 mb-0 me-1 text-primary">P</sup>
                  <h1 class="display-4 mb-0 text-primary">'.$row['itemcost'].'</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br/>
              <a href="./protected/webhook-alerts/shop-purchase.php?desc='.$row['itemdesc'].'" method="post" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-grid w-100 post">'.$status.'</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  ';
```